# Valor errado ao criar dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Estou querendo criar um dataFrame com 2 colunas - `meses` e `valor`. Só que os valores da coluna valor estão vindo de forma errada. Mostrando passo a passo do que estou fazendo:

Soma o total de cada mês de outros arquivos:

```
janeiro = round(sum(lic01.Valor_Licitação), 2)
fevereiro = round(sum(lic02.Valor_Licitação), 2)
março = round(sum(lic03.Valor_Licitação), 2)
abril = round(sum(lic04.Valor_Licitação), 2)
maio = round(sum(lic05.Valor_Licitação), 2)
junho = round(sum(lic06.Valor_Licitação), 2)
julho = round(sum(lic07.Valor_Licitação), 2)
agosto = round(sum(lic08.Valor_Licitação), 2)
```

E com isso crio um novo dataFrame:

```
meses = pd.DataFrame({'Meses' : ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto'], 'Valor':[janeiro, fevereiro, março, abril, maio, junho, julho, agosto]})
meses.to_csv=()
```

E o dataFrame fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso de modo que os valores sejam apresentados de forma correta?

Comment: Guilherme, boa tarde! Seu números estão sendo apresentados em notação científica. Tem como disponibilizar o dataset? Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma estudada melhor e consegui resolver. Obrigado e desculpe por qualquer coisa.
Apliquei:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)
```